# How to delete all unused variables in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm

How to delete all unused variables in a project in WebStorm or other editor?

I have a lot of unused CommonJS imports like this. I'd like to remove them from my project.

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

Comment: That notation has nothing to do with ES5, it is CommonJS. What do you mean by "for es6 imports"? Do you want to replace them with the ES6 module syntax?

Comment: If you have Eslint correctly configured which includes `no-unused-*` you can easily using the fix command: https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2016/08/using-external-tools/

Comment: @Hitmands that's a good idea. thanks.

Comment: @str No, I want to delete imports which aren't used. I have updated my question.

Comment: ``no-unused-vars`` rule are not fixeble eslint.org/docs/rules

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can remove all unused variable in current file using quickfix:

- hit `Alt+Enter` on unused variable, hit `Right`
- Choose '*Fix all 'Unused JavaScript/ActionScript local symbol' problems in file*'

[image]

If fixing the problem for each file individually is not an option for you, try using ESLint auto-fix per @Hitmands suggestion